# Databinding with kind of join over two lists

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am familiar with the basics of databinding in wpf. However I now have a problem which I wonder how to solve.

Imagine following use case:

I have a global ObservableCollection called "AItems" of Type A.
I have some Objects of Type B and each has a ObservableCollection "BItems" of type A.
The BItems Collections can contain Objects of the global AItems Collection.

I want to visualize this by a ListView.
Each line should contain an A-Object and a checkbox.
I want the ListView to show all elements of the AItems-Collection. Items which are assigned to the B-Object should be marked with a checked checkbox. All other checkboxes should be unchecked.

My questions are now:
How should I set the datacontext?
How can I make that checking a checkbox inserts its item to the BItems-Collection and unchecking removes it?

I hope anyone can understand my problem.

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on the latter part of your question.  Partly it's because your naming convention is confusing; I'd expect a collection named `BItems` to contain objects of type `B`, not `A`.

So I'm going to change your nomenclature a bit so that I don't get confused.  Instead of `A`, I'll call the first class `User`, and instead of `B`, I'll call the second class `Group`.  A `Group` contains a collection of `User` objects, named `Users`.  The global collections look like this:

```
List<User> Users;
List<Group> Groups;
```

It's easy to determine if a given `User` `u` is in any group:

```
return Groups.Where(g => g.Users.Contains(u)).Any();
```

Easy, but computationally expensive if you have many groups and they contain many users.  We'll get back to that in a second.

Right away, I see that one of your questions has got a problem:

> How can I make that checking a checkbox inserts its item to the BItems-Collection and unchecking removes it?

What should happen if I check an unchecked user?  Which group (or groups, since more than one group can contain a user) should it be added to?

Since you say that you want checked items to be "assigned to the B-Object", I'm going to assume that the UI is only looking at one group at a time - we'll call it the `SelectedGroup`.  This is good, because `g.Users.Contains(u)` is much less expensive than the query I showed above.

If this is so, what you need to do is wrap your `User` in a class that exposes an `IsChecked` property.  I'd call this class `UserViewModel`, since that's what it is.  The class needs three properties (at a minimum):

```
public User User { get; set; }

public Group SelectedGroup { get; set; }

public bool IsChecked
{ 
   get { return SelectedGroup.Users.Contains(this.User); } 
   set
   {
      if (value != IsChecked)
      {
         if (IsChecked)
         {
            SelectedGroup.Users.Remove(this.User);
         }
         else
         {
            SelectedGroup.Users.Add(this.User);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Your `ListView` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>` named, say, `UserViewModels`.  Whenever `SelectedGroup` is set, you need to rebuild this collection:

```
UserViewModels = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>(
   Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel { User=u, SelectedGroup=SelectedGroup }));
```

You could avoid rebuilding the collection by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `UserViewModel` class, and having it raise `PropertyChanged` for the `IsChecked` property whenever `SelectedGroup` changes.

Also, it would probably be responsible to include null-reference checking in the `IsChecked` property, so that the program doesn't throw an exception if `SelectedGroup` or `SelectedGroup.Users` is null.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing naming convention. Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. My GUI indeed always shows only one 'group'at time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a list box to Aitems and using a converter to set the isChecked property

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource BItemCheckConverter}}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

public class BItemCheckConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public List<Aitems> BItems { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (BItems.Contains((value as Aitems)) return true;
        else return false
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I don't know how's your object model, so take the above code as is.

HTH